# dropdown selected value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a little problem. 
How can I select value with value id?

this is my code:

```
string actionId = new MyRptSubReportEntity().GetReportAction(this.SubReportId).ToString();
if (actionId == "0") actionId = "4";
// this.drpActionList.SelectedIndex =int.Parse(actionId);
this.drpActionList.SelectedValue = actionId;
```

but it is not working. Actionid is coming from the database.

Thanks for your answers.
John

Comment: Can you provide a code/html example? Also, are you looking to do it in JS on the client or in C# on the server?

Comment: what are all the item values?

Answer (score 2):

```
dropdown.SelectedValue = value;
```

[linky](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx)

Comment: this is my code 
 string actionId = new MyRptSubReportEntity().GetReportAction(this.SubReportId).ToString();

            if (actionId == "0")
                actionId = "4";

           // this.drpActionList.SelectedIndex =int.Parse(actionId);

            this.drpActionList.SelectedValue = actionId;              but it is not working. actionid is coming database.